# Is a measurable function on a bounded closed set "almost bounded"?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\varphi(x)$ is a measurable function, defined on a bounded closed set $\Omega$.Show that:$\varphi(x)$ is almost bounded on $\Omega$.Namely:
$$
\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists M>0,st,mE[x\in\Omega:|\varphi(x)|>M]<\varepsilon 
$$

Comment: I don't think "bounded, closed" has much to do with it. "Finite measure" is the important thing.

Comment: @zhw. You are right.  $\Omega$  don't need to a bounded closed set.  All we need is $\Omega$ to have finite measure.  Of course, we also need $\varphi$ to have only  finite values (see my answer below).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro   Sorry, I don't understand you,Forgive my poor English. Could you help me edit the question making it's suitable ?Or, giving a more detailed description?Thanks very much.

Comment: I think the title is OK now, with the use of "almost bounded". Instead of "almost bounded", one could also say "nearly bounded". I don't think there is a standard terminology for this notion, however. Incidentally, the notion is the same that is often used in stating [Littlewood's Three Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_three_principles_of_real_analysis). I'll remove my comments in a few hours since they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the range of $\varphi$?  If you allow $\varphi$ to have $\pm\infty$ values then the result is false.  Let $\varphi: [0,2] \to [0,+\infty]$  be defined as $\varphi(x)= +\infty$ if $x \in [0,1)$  and  $\varphi(x)= 0$ if $x \in [1,2]$.  The function $\varphi$ is measurable, $[0,2]$ is a bounded and closed set, but $\varphi$  is NOT almost bounded on $[0,2]$.

Now, let us assume that range of $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and that $\Omega$ has finite measure.

Let $B_n=\{x\in \Omega \,|\, n\leqslant \vert \varphi(x) \vert<n+1\} $, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is easy to see that if $n\neq m$ the $B_n\cap B_m=\emptyset$. We also have $\Omega=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$. So we have

$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(B_n) =\mu(\Omega) <+\infty$$

So we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n =k}^\infty\mu(B_n)=0$, that is,  $\lim_{k \to \infty}\mu[\vert\varphi\vert\geqslant k]=0$. So $\varphi$ is almost bounded.

Comment: Thanks ,your answer is what I really need.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $A_n=\{x\in \Omega; |\varphi(x)|\leq n\}$. Show that $A_n$ is a measurable subset of $\Omega$, that $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ and $\cup A_n=\Omega$, and use these informations.